# Agent forwarding and `sudo` vs `sudo -i`

Tags: ssh, x11, ssh-agent

Under an `ssh -X -A localhost` session, `sudo xeyes` opens the eyes but `sudo -i xeyes` does not.

```
~$ sudo -i xeyes
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

What extra step is needed in order to make `sudo -i xeyes` open the eyes too? Other than removing the `-i`, of course.

Comment: Crosspost: https://serverfault.com/questions/916991/agent-forwarding-and-sudo-vs-sudo-i

Comment: This is weird. Before migration I was actually able to close it without having to vote...

Comment: Now that both are here you can delete this one, I guess.